# Conditionally move files in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have a simple SSIS package with a ForEach Loop Container with 1 Data Flow task that triggers when a file is present. If that task succeeds, I want to move the input file to a "success" folder. If it fails, I want to move the file to an "error" folder. I am not seeing an error (red arrow) from the data flow task. How do I access the error condition for the data flow task?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to my question.

The answer that worked for me was to add the 2nd move File System Task. Then when connecting to previous Data Flow Task, right click on the Precedence Constraint and click the "Failure" option.  I now have my error condition!